# is $G/Z(G)$ an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $Z(G)$ is its centre. Then $G/Z(G)$ is the quotient group. then is $G/Z(G)$ an abelian group? Here $G/Z(G)$ is the group of cosets of $Z(G)$ in $G$.

Comment: No, $G/Z(G)$ need not be abelian. For example, take $G=S_3$. Even if $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$, $G/Z(G)$ may not be abelian. Take the dihedral group of order $16$.

Comment: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. This is a quite standard exercise which could be found in any group theory textbook.

Answer (score 3):

$G/Z(G)\cong\operatorname{Inn}G$ then if you take an $S_n$ for n>3 you now that $G/Z(G)\cong\operatorname G$ .

But there is the Commutator subgroup : see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Abelianization.html

Answer (score 0):

$G/Z(G)\cong\operatorname{Inn}G$, the so-called *inner automorphism* group of $G$.  It isn't always abelian.

Suppose the center is trivial, as for $S_n,n\ge3$,; or, for the dihedral groups $D_n$, when $n$ is odd, to take some easy examples.

It is fairly straightforward to prove that when $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, $G$ is abelian.